What is the story between Jesus and Mary of Magdala?
I am looking into a myth:
is there any evidence to the claim that Jesus and Mary of Magdala may have had an intimate relationship like either marriage or being engaged at least?
I'm looking for sources, solid ones.

If I recall correctly, there's no evidence that the story is true, but it originated with the Gnostics early on and was recently popularized again by the Da Vinci Code

@DarkMalthorp rather, the Da Vinci Code popularized the legend that the story originated with the Gnostics.

@user111403 thanks for the clarification! I have read neither the gnostic texts nor Da Vinci Code; my comment was based solely on rumor

Yeah, I don't much to add to the answers. The Great and Holy myrrh-Bearer Mary Magdalene, Equal to the Apostles, Apostle to the Apostles.... she definitely had some kind of close relationship. But nothing like marriage or being engaged. Nope.

The non-canonical Gospel of Philip describes a special relationship between Jesus and Magdalene. Whether it involved physical sex is another matter. The text is fragmentary in a crucial spot but here is one translation:

Mary Magdalene. [...he?] loved her more than all the disciples, and used
to kiss her often on her mouth. The rest of the disciples [...]. They
said to him "Why do you love her more than all of us?"

The kiss on the mouth may or may not have been romantic. But for this writer, it was more than simply a "kiss of peace" as in orthodox traditions. Earlier in this gospel we find the following:

It is by a kiss that the perfect conceive and give birth. For this
reason we also kiss one another. We receive conception from the grace
which is in one another. There were three who always walked with the
Lord: Mary, his mother, and her sister, and Magdalene, the one who was
called his companion. His sister and his mother and his companion were
each a Mary.

It is therefore logical to conclude that in the Gospel of Philip, Jesus and Mary are portrayed has being involved in an intimate relationship of kissing, which produced "conception" and "birth." However, both of these seem to be understood spiritually rather than physically.
Among the canonical gospels, John portrays Mary as being the first to see Jesus. The two are alone in an isolated place, but Jesus does not allow Mary to touch/hold him. (John 20:17) Luke speaks of an unnamed "sinful woman" of Capernaum who bathed Jesus' feet - an act normally reserved to a man's wife. (Luke 7:37ff) Mark, Matthew and John refer to a similar event in a different location (Bethany), where a woman named Mary performs this act; but she is not called sinful and seems to a different person than Magdalene (she is Lazarus' sister).
Summary. These are some of the salient biblical and gnostic texts dealing with this issue. They do not provide direct evidence for the hypothesis that Jesus was either married or engaged to Magdalene. However, the Gospel of Philip does suggest that they were at least spiritually intimate, and that they "conceived" and "gave birth" through kissing.

All of these "evidences" require major stretches. Regarding the canonical Gospels, The precise meaning of of "touch me not" is disputed, but regarding it as sexual is a fringe view and doesn't really make sense in context ("for I have not yet departed to My Father"? The straightforward reading is "let go of me, I'm not leaving yet"). The claim regarding footwashing falls flat because, as you yourself noted, we have accounts of at least two women washing Christ's feet.

As for the Gospel of Philip, other Gnostic writings portray Mary as Jesus' preferred disciple, who received special teaching from Him and as a result was envied by the other disciples, specifically Peter. The Gospel of Mary explicitly ties their envy to teaching she received, rather than any kind of physical relationship. None suggest a sexual relationship. Philip makes perfect sense in this context; I'll admit there may be more to the kiss than I thought, but it's still hard to see this as sexual, especially given Gnostic views on the physical and spiritual.

As  I mentioned Philip's gospel seems to see the conception and birth as spiritual, but the kiss as physical. This provides an answer to the question to the OP's question as to sources for a possible intimate relationship. In another answer I argue that Magdalene's being alone with Jesus right after the resurrection may (stress "may") be understood to involve a suggestion of intimacy.

even if we accept the interpretation presented (which I think is far-fetched), then it still follows from Jesus' rebuff that there was no physical relationship between them.

I don't intend to debate the issue, but I should point out that I am simply answering the OP question not arguing that there actually was a sexual relationship between Jesus and Magdalene.

Close enough, it is a Gnostic "Gospel" that twists stuff around in weird ways. Nice answer.

This answer will suffice for me, and! As an add up to the mystery: in John, 21:25 it says: "Jesus did many other things as well. If every one of them were written down, I suppose that even the whole world would not have room for the books that would be written." There may be more to this Man than we can comprehend!

In short, no.
The claim that Jesus and Mary Magdalene were married is often attributed to early Gnostic manuscripts. While the Gnostics to place a lot of emphasis on Mary Magdalene, this specific claim isn't true. None of the Gnostic writings we have claim a physical relationship. The nearest is the Gospel of Philip, which refers to Jesus kissing Mary, however that, at the time, was a common greeting among Christians (see Judas' kiss in Gethsemane and Paul's writings) and did not imply sexuality. The claimed "lost gospel" is also a modern hoax, it's based on an ancient document of uncertain date called Joseph and Asenath, which tells the story of, as you'd expect, Joseph and Asenath. The "lost gospel" theory claims, based on - well, nothing, really, that this is really an allegory for Jesus and Mary.
The earliest somewhat reliable source for this claim comes from the 13th century Catharist sect. Multiple Catholic authors (including Pierre des Vaux-de-Cernay) claim that the Cathars taught that Mary was the wife or concubine of Jesus. It should be noted that these accounts come from hostile sources at a time when the Cathars were being actively persecuted, but at least we can say that it was widely believed to be part of their teachings. Therefore it's reasonable to conclude that the conspiracy theory had begun to pop up at least by the Middle Ages. However, that's already over a thousand years after Christ. There is no contemporary evidence for the theory and the vast majority of secular as well as religious historians don't take it seriously.

I won't downvote this but I have to disagree about the implication of the Gospel of Philip. We should also note hints in the canonical gospels (not that these constitute strong evidence). I will summarize in my own answer.

@DanFefferman I have to disagree with your disagreement. There are no "hints" in the gospels, at most one text that can somehow be forced to fit the theory. As for Philip, I may have understated the argument somewhat, but it definitely doesn't describe Mary as Jesus' wife and reading it as describing a sexual relationship is a fringe view.
